# How to horizontally align buttons in different elements

Tags: html, css, django

I have 3 buttons in different divs with different content. I would like all the divs to be the same height and to horizontally align the 3 buttons.

Below is an image that shows the current page, and the desired page with the styling I'd like to achieve. But I just added margins manually in the dev console, so it's not using best practice (see the below image to see how it looks on an Ipad, not very good).

[image]

And here is what it looks like on iPad (because I just manually added margin-top to each div).

[image]

**Does anyone know the proper way to achieve this? Below is the code:**

```css
 @import url(https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:800);
    
    
    .snip1214 {
      font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    }
    
    
    /* MOBILE CUSTOMIZATIONS */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .snip1214 .plan {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 90px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .snip1214 .plan {
        min-height: 350px;
        max-height: 350px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 33%;
        float: left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      .plan-select {
        display: grid;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .snip1214 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
    
    
    
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #212121;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-flow: wrap;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .snip1214 * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .snip1214 header {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .snip1214 .plan-title {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #222f3d;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-cost {
      padding: 0px 10px 20px;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-price {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 2.4em;
      color: #34495e;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-type {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      list-style: outside none none;
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features li {
      border-top: 1px solid #d2d7e2;
      padding: 10px 5%;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features li:nth-child(even) {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features i {
      margin-right: 8px;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-select {
      border-top: 1px solid #d2d7e2;
      padding: 10px 10px 0;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-select a {
      background-color: #222f3d;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
      transform: translateY(50%);
      font-weight: 800;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-select a:hover {
      background-color: #46627f;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured {
      margin-top: -10px;
      background-color: #34495e;
      color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-title,
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-price {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-cost {
      padding: 10px 10px 20px;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-features li {
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-select {
      padding: 20px 10px 0;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
```

```html
    <div style="margin: 50px 0 50px 0; color: #ffffff; text-align: center">
      <h2>Game Exchange Pricing</h2>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="snip1214">
    
      <div class="plan">
        <h3 class="plan-title">
          Free
        </h3>
        <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$0</span></div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Up to 2 Committed Offers at a time</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Ads displayed</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Live chat to arrange meeting</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Get Free</a></div>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="plan featured">
        <h3 class="plan-title">
          Standard
        </h3>
        <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$2.49</span><span class="plan-type">/ Monthly</span></div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Up to 4 Committed Offers at a time</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>No Ads</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Live chat to arrange meeting</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Get Standard</a></div>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="plan">
        <h3 class="plan-title">
          Premium
        </h3>
        <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$6.99</span><span class="plan-type">/ Monthly</span></div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Up to 6 Committed Offers at a time</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Desired Game Search<br />
            <i>See what games you could trade away to get a game you want in exchange</i>
          </li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>No Ads</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Live chat to arrange meeting</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Get Premium</a></div>
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set position:relative for the parent (`.plan`) and set position: absolute for the button element to place it below `bottom: 30px;`

```css
 @import url(https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,800);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:800);
    
    
    .snip1214 {
      font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
    }
    
    
    /* MOBILE CUSTOMIZATIONS */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .snip1214 .plan {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 90px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .snip1214 .plan {
        min-height: 350px;
        max-height: 350px;
        margin: 0;
        width: 33%;
        float: left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }
      .plan-select {
        display: grid;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .snip1214 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
    
    
    
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #212121;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-flow: wrap;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .snip1214 * {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .snip1214 header {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .snip1214 .plan-title {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      font-weight: 800;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #222f3d;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-cost {
      padding: 0px 10px 20px;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-price {
      font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 2.4em;
      color: #34495e;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-type {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      list-style: outside none none;
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features li {
      border-top: 1px solid #d2d7e2;
      padding: 10px 5%;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features li:nth-child(even) {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-features i {
      margin-right: 8px;
      opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-select {
      border-top: 1px solid #d2d7e2;
      padding: 10px 10px 0;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-select a {
      background-color: #222f3d;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0.5em 1em;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
      transform: translateY(50%);
      font-weight: 800;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .snip1214 .plan-select a:hover {
      background-color: #46627f;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured {
      margin-top: -10px;
      background-color: #34495e;
      color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-title,
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-price {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-cost {
      padding: 10px 10px 20px;
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-features li {
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
    .snip1214 .featured .plan-select {
      padding: 20px 10px 0;
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
    

.plan  {
  position: relative;
}

.plan .plan-select {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .plan .plan-select  {position: initial;}
  .plan .plan-select a{transform: none; margin-bottom: 10px;}
}
```

```html
 <div style="margin: 50px 0 50px 0; color: #ffffff; text-align: center">
      <h2>Game Exchange Pricing</h2>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="snip1214">
    
      <div class="plan">
        <h3 class="plan-title">
          Free
        </h3>
        <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$0</span></div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Up to 2 Committed Offers at a time</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Ads displayed</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Live chat to arrange meeting</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Get Free</a></div>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="plan featured">
        <h3 class="plan-title">
          Standard
        </h3>
        <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$2.49</span><span class="plan-type">/ Monthly</span></div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Up to 4 Committed Offers at a time</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>No Ads</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Live chat to arrange meeting</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Get Standard</a></div>
      </div>
    
    
      <div class="plan">
        <h3 class="plan-title">
          Premium
        </h3>
        <div class="plan-cost"><span class="plan-price">$6.99</span><span class="plan-type">/ Monthly</span></div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Up to 6 Committed Offers at a time</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Desired Game Search<br />
            <i>See what games you could trade away to get a game you want in exchange</i>
          </li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>No Ads</li>
          <li><i class="ion-checkmark"> </i>Live chat to arrange meeting</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="plan-select"><a href="">Get Premium</a></div>
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
```

And on mobile view toggle the button's position back to initial and set margin bottom and remove the transform property

Comment: That's amazing, exactly what i was looking for and looks great on mobile and desktop. Thanks for your help @Virra!

Comment: Happy to help :)